# What is the meaning of infinite covariance?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, data-analysis

When I fit a line to a given set of data points then all the elements of the covariance matrix comes out to be infinite . What is the meaning of this infinite covariance and what measures I should take?

Comment: Could you provide more details ? Are you talking about an implementation on a "real" data set ?

Comment: Yeah! I have a raw data set and I fit it with a function and find the covariance between the raw data and points on the fitted line.

Comment: How do you compute it ?

Comment: I use the method of least squares to find the fit. Here is the python function I use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Comment: Ok, good to know. But I was talking about the covariance. It is unlikely that a real life sample generates numbers overcoming the computer abilities.